# How to connect a vm to the internet in Cloonix?

Tags: networking, virtual, simulation

I have a cloonix simulated network with debian virtual machines.
I'd like to install and update stuff on the vms. 
How do I connect them to internet via my host computer ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not ask the author?
You should not rely on help on cloonix, communication on the product has been small and not many know about it.

To reach the internet from a virtual machine, the host must be connected to the internet and the file /etc/resolv.conf of the host must be valid.
If the above is ok, then connect an interface of the vm to the cloonix_slirp_admin_vlan and do dhclient on this interface from within the guest.
Then your vm should be connected to the internet (check your /etc/apt/sources.list to have apt-get).

Comment: Did not think of asking the author! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should connect `eth1` (for example) of vm to `"cloonix_slirp_admin_vlan"` which is always in hidden. Then input `"dhclient eth1"` in the console of vm, then the vm can connect to the Internet. There is an example, I hope it will help you:

http://www.brianlinkletter.com/upgrade-a-guest-vm-in-the-cloonix-network-simulator/